# why iOS widget always omit the text even when there are lot of space to fill

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widget

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lra6N.jpg)
this is my view code for a simple widget
and ios always omit my text by ... which only have 4 characters

```
var body: some View {
        Text("更多\(5)个")
    }
```

as long as I use the interpolation and Chinese together
it won't display correctly

```
Text("\(5) more to check")
```

Comment: All works fine If I remove all your dynamic parts, like `mostRecentFood!.remainTime` which are not available for me) - maybe they are too long and w/o space chars... Try to debug that info, comment it out and add one by one.

Comment: OMG, this drives my crazy, I found that if i use static string text both chinese and english are fine, but if I combine \() the string interpolation with text, only english can display properly, chinese will shrink to 1 character, is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very strange solution
you need to add a space at the end of the text and it'll show all the text
thank god for finally working it out.